# how to segment different times in a day in r

Tags: r

I'm working on a project and now I have this col which records different time points during a day. there are countless rows in my dataset.
Here's what I got after using unique function to give you an idea:

```r
unique(cab_rides_filtered$time)
[1] 03:46:40 19:53:20 20:53:20 22:53:20 21:53:20 13:06:40 00:26:40 14:46:40 01:53:20 07:00:00
[11] 10:00:00 13:33:20 18:20:00 06:20:00 14:40:00 17:40:00 20:13:20 14:33:20 08:13:20 01:00:00
[21] 15:20:00 05:46:40 20:06:40 12:06:40 03:13:20 15:53:20 22:13:20 18:40:00 15:40:00 17:33:20
```

I converted the column into the times format by using

`chron(times = cab_rides_filtered$time)`

I want to segment 24 hours in a day into 8 day zones, and segment all these time points that I have right now into a new column called day zone, for example, day zone 1 is from 00:00:00 to 02:59:59.

```r
time                   day zone
03:46:40                  2

dput(unique(cab_rides_filtered$time))

structure(c(0.157407407407407, 0.828703703703704, 0.87037037037037, 
0.953703703703704, 0.912037037037037, 0.546296296296296, 0.0185185185185185, 
0.615740740740741, 0.0787037037037037, 0.291666666666667, 0.416666666666667, 
0.564814814814815, 0.763888888888889, 0.263888888888889, 0.611111111111111, 
0.736111111111111, 0.842592592592593, 0.606481481481482, 0.342592592592593, 
0.0416666666666667, 0.638888888888889, 0.240740740740741, 0.837962962962963, 
0.50462962962963, 0.134259259259259, 0.662037037037037, 0.925925925925926, 
0.777777777777778, 0.652777777777778, 0.731481481481482, 0.944444444444444, 
0.5, 0.152777777777778, 0.99537037037037, 0.333333333333333, 
0.305555555555556, 0.115740740740741, 0.217592592592593, 0.273148148148148, 
0.810185185185185, 0.347222222222222, 0.175925925925926, 0.449074074074074, 
0.365740740740741, 0.921296296296296, 0.490740740740741, 0.962962962962963, 
0.796296296296296, 0.425925925925926, 0.148148148148148, 0.407407407407407, 
0.0277777777777778, 0.300925925925926, 0.194444444444444, 0.532407407407407, 
0.199074074074074, 0.143518518518519, 0.75462962962963, 0.0324074074074074, 
0.768518518518518, 0.722222222222222, 0.537037037037037, 0.893518518518518, 
0.680555555555556, 0.541666666666667, 0.226851851851852, 0.523148148148148, 
0.773148148148148, 0.884259259259259, 0.37962962962963, 0.907407407407407, 
0.037037037037037, 0.657407407407407, 0.0833333333333333, 0.847222222222222, 
0.574074074074074, 0.587962962962963, 0.25, 0.259259259259259, 
0.189814814814815, 0.578703703703704, 0.481481481481481, 0.00925925925925926, 
0.314814814814815, 0.388888888888889, 0, 0.888888888888889, 0.712962962962963, 
0.268518518518519, 0.125, 0.0694444444444444, 0.87962962962963, 
0.805555555555556, 0.648148148148148, 0.851851851851852, 0.231481481481481, 
0.310185185185185, 0.00462962962962963, 0.967592592592593, 0.49537037037037, 
0.694444444444444, 0.356481481481481, 0.958333333333333, 0.597222222222222, 
0.62037037037037, 0.111111111111111, 0.375, 0.472222222222222, 
0.421296296296296, 0.0740740740740741, 0.0601851851851852, 0.726851851851852, 
0.185185185185185, 0.462962962962963, 0.916666666666667, 0.430555555555556, 
0.689814814814815, 0.384259259259259, 0.458333333333333, 0.791666666666667, 
0.101851851851852, 0.12037037037037, 0.902777777777778), format = "h:m:s", class = "times")
```

Comment: @d.b.  dput(unique(cab_rides_filtered$time))
structure(c(0.157407407407407, 0.828703703703704, 0.87037037037037, 
0.953703703703704, 0.912037037037037, 0.546296296296296, 0.0185185185185185, 
0.615740740740741, 0.0787037037037037, ..., 0.902777777777778), format = "h:m:s", class = "times")

Comment: @d.b hi, the above output is omitted because it's too long and I couldn't post it here

Comment: Please put the output into the text of your question by editing it. That will give you more room and make it easy to find for anyone who can help.

Comment: @d.b please see the complete output above.